# How to publicly access an AWS EC2 instance that contains an SSL redirect?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Node/Express server running on an EC2 instance that is maintained by Elastic Beanstalk (single instance no load balancer).
I am struggling with implementing a correct SSL redirect that works with EC2.

The SSL redirect is as follows:

```
const httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/local/ssl/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/local/ssl/cert.pem'),
  passphrase: '*****'
}

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  let httpsHost = req.headers.host.replace('8081', '8443');
  res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + httpsHost + req.url });
  res.end();
}).listen(8081);

https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen(8443)
```

This works great locally, but when I deploy to my EC2 instance and try to access the site, I get:

[image]

Here is a picture of my inbound rules as well:

[image]

Do I have the ports configured incorrectly? I cannot use port 80 and port 443 because it requires root permissions, and I won't run my server with root permissions.

Comment: Have you allowed port 8443 in inbound rules?

Comment: @NyagakaEnock I added a photo of my inbound rules, what do I need to add?

Comment: Are you using a load balancer? Or is this a single-instance Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Comment: @MarkB This is a single-instance ELB environment

Comment: @JakeChambers be careful with your acronyms. In AWS, ELB stands for Elastic Load Balancer, not Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: @MarkB Noted, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Is there some sort of Apache or Nginx server running in front of the Node server to proxy requests on port 80/443 to ports `8081` and `8443`? Isn't that usually how Elastic Beanstalk pre-configures these environments? You would need to install the SSL certificate and configure the redirect in that reverse-proxy server, not in your Node server.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to access your host on port 443 I get a response, which means the host is accessible. When I try to access your server on port 8443, I receive a "Connection timed out", what could possibly be caused by wrong firewall (ie. security group) settings.

Your server instance listens to port 8443 and 8081, but in your security group rules the ports 443 and 80 are configured. If you cannot use 443/80 as you wrote, please edit the inbound rules to allow traffic from ports 8443/8081 instead.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved through port forwarding.

Check current IP-tables:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L
```

Remove last entry:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 1
```

Set up redirection as necessary, in my case:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8081
```

This sends all 443 traffic to 8443, and all 80 traffic to 8081.